# Gimp Script-Fu: Delete a selection

Tags: scheme, gimp, script-fu

I'm trying to write a script for Gimp that will crop an image, make a circular selection of what's left, invert the selection, and then delete the selection. I have the cropping, selection, and inversion part done, but the deleting is what's getting me.

(removed old code, see update)

That's the code I have. What's confusing me about the `gimp-item-delete` code is the `item`. I understand that I need to define my current selection as the `item`, but I'm not sure how to do this. If someone could explain how to do this, I would greatly appreciate it! Alternatively, if there's an easier way to do what I'm trying to do (but preferably still in a script), please let me know what you think. My knowledge of this coding is pretty limited, so simple explanations are appreciated.

UPDATE/EDIT:
Here's the (full) updated code:

```
; XML2 Conversation Portrait Preview Crop
(define (script-fu-xml2-convo-preview image layer)
    (gimp-image-undo-group-start image)
    (gimp-selection-none image)
    (gimp-image-resize image 152 152 -280 -496)
    (gimp-layer-resize-to-image-size layer)
    (gimp-image-select-ellipse image 0 0 0 152 152)
    (gimp-selection-invert image)
    (gimp-displays-flush)
    (gimp-drawable-edit-clear layer)
    (gimp-selection-none image) 
    (gimp-image-undo-group-end image)
)
; populate script registration information
(script-fu-register 
    "script-fu-xml2-convo-preview"
    "XML2 Conversation Portrait Preview Crop"
    "Crops the preview window for XML2 conversation portraits."
    "BaconWizard17"
    "BaconWizard17"
    "September 2021"
    "*"
    SF-IMAGE        "Image"       0
    SF-DRAWABLE     "Layer"       0
)
; register the script within gimp menu
(script-fu-menu-register "script-fu-xml2-convo-preview" "<Image>/Marvel Mods/Skin Previews/XML2 PC")
```

So when I'm running this script, it appears to just crop it and doesn't delete the inverted circular selection. However, if I interact with the image in any way (click on it, duplicated it, copy/paste it, undo/redo), it will correct itself and show the properly cropped image with the deleted circular corners. When I first run the script, it also shows the incorrect image up at the top where you can pick which image you're working on, but after interacting with the image it will show the correct image. Here's an example:

The starting image that I create from the clipboard with Ctrl+Shift+V (after screenshotting it from the game using PrtScr):

[image: How the image looks when I copy it in from my clipboard]

Then, I run the script, which results in this:

[image: How the image looks after I initially run the script. The background that I'm trying to delete is still visible]

At the top of the screen, the image shows up like this (which is the top left 152x152 pixels of the starting image:

[image: The image's thumbnail at the top of the screen, showing the wrong portion of the image]

How the image looks once I interact with it in any way (clicking on it, copy/pasting it, duplicating it, undoing/redoing the operation):

[image: The correctly cropped image after I interact with it]

The thumbnail at the top of the screen after I interact with the image:

[image: The thumbnail at the top of the screen showing the correct image]

Maybe it's getting hung up on something during the operation? I'm not sure. I understand if this issue is unavoidable, but I would prefer to be able to just run the script and move on rather than having to interact with the image to get it to show up correctly. The image does have an alpha layer when it's pasted in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gimp-item-delete` is a memory/object management thing and is rarely used. What you are looking for is `gimp-drawable-edit-clear`.

Note that it should be done (together with your final `gimp-selection-none`) before `gimp-image-undo-group-end` if you want your whole script to be undone by a single `Ctrl-Z`.

Edit: It appears that your code works, it's just that the display isn't updated to show the result, which is exactly what `gimp-display-flush` is meant to do, so why is your code calling it **before** `gimp-drawable-edit-clear`? `gimp-display-flush` ought to be about the last thing done by your script.

Comment: That does seem to be what I'm looking for. It looks like the parameter that that command needs is `drawable`. How can I set my selection to be that? Or should I just do `gimp-drawable-edit-clear layer`?

Comment: Yes, it uses implicitly the current selection (like when you do `[del]` or `Edit >> Clear` in the UI)

Comment: So I tried that, and it's being a bit weird. When I execute the command, it just crops it to a square and doesn't delete anything. However, if I undo it and redo it, then it correctly shows up cropped and as a circle. What could be the reason for that? Should I post my code again? If so, what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: Yes, please update your question with the new code, and perhaps before/after screenshots. Is there an alpha channel on the layer (if in boldface in the Layer list => No alpha channel)? `gimp-drawable-edit-clear` requires one if you want transparency in the corners.

Comment: I added my updated script to the top, as well as what happens when I run it.

Comment: See edited answer

Comment: Man, I have no clue how I missed that. Thank you for catching it! Marking as resolved now.